# VSCode use quickpick list items with description

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created vscode extension with `quickpick`, the quickpick show list of items

```
const pick = await input.showQuickPick({
            title,
            step: 1,
            totalSteps: 3,
            placeholder: 'Choose runtime',
            items: Runtimes,
            activeItem: typeof state.resourceGroup !== 'string' ? state.resourceGroup : undefined,
            // buttons: [createResourceGroupButton],
            shouldResume: shouldResume
        });
```

Now I was able to show list of data which user can choose like

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

My question if there is a way to show the data with name and description ?

like

```
aaaa            desc for aaaa  
bbbb            desc for bbbb
cccc            desc for cccc
```

I mean to add additional info to the list?  like maybe key value
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPick

if it's not possible, please let me know

for example the **test1/2** is the value which I want to add to each entry

[image]

Answer (score 6):

VSCode [showQuickPick](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showQuickPick) can take `string[]` (string array) or [QuickPickItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem) array as items. I think you are looking for [QuickPickItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem).

Check [VSCode examples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/aa42c2ec7248059ff5903ff11aa6eeabc04329bf/configuration-sample/src/extension.ts#L34), where the usage of [QuickPickItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem) is shown.

The result would look something like below:
[image]

where:

- left most string is the `label`
- right most string is `description`
- bottom left string is `detail`

*The looks of the default Quick Pick provided do not allow floating labels to left or right, they are all left-aligned and follow the LTR layout.*

> P.S. You can try [window.createQuickPick](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createQuickPick), but again it gives you more control over the popup, and not the styling of the popup.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a class that implements `QuickPickItem` and then pass a list of those objects to the `showQuickPick`.

So something like this

```
class MyItem implements QuickPickItem {
  label: string;
  description = '';
  
  constructor(public detail: string, name: string) {
    this.label = `Custom ${name}`;
  }
}

// in your code assuming you have a list of items that you map to this object
  const options = items.map((item) => {
    return new MyItem(
      item.desc,
      item.name,
    );
  });

// this window is imported from 'vscode'
  const pick = await window.showQuickPick(options, {
    title,
    canPickMany: false,
    // any other properties you need
  });
```